# How to open posts with url as popup windows like in Reddit or Twitter?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, popup, reddit

I am working on a React application and I want to open a post in a home feed like a popup. The similar thing happens in Reddit and Twitter which keeps the home feed's scrolled position restored when you close the post or the tweet.
Can someone help me how to approach this?